# How to override Vuetify variables with custom colors?

Tags: stylus, vuetify.js

I want to override vuetify variables with custom colors by following [this](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/style/theme#stylus-guide)

I've created a stylus folder which contains base folder (`_colors`, `_typography`) and `main.styl` file.  The `_color` file is imported into `main.styl` file, which the latter is imported into `main.js`

Here is my file structure:

[image]

And the imports are included in `main.js`:

```
 import '../node_modules/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
 import './assets/stylus/main.styl'
```

Inside the `_color.styl`, I have this test code:

```
$red = {
  "base":       #FF0000,
  "darken-1":   #e50000,
  "darken-2":   #990000,
  "darken-3":   #7f0000,
  "darken-4":   #000000,
}
```

The custom colors aren't showing...am I missing something here?

Comment: Since you're importing the vuetify.min.css, it's already CSS. The variables its using have already been replaced and transformed into browser-legible CSS. To change the colors of Vuetify, you should use a theme: https://vuetifyjs.com/style/theme

Answer (score 13):

As @webdevdani mentionned it, I don't think overriding vuetify style is possible.

I propose you a workaround : use a `theme`.

In your `main.js` you can set colors, like this :

```js
Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  theme: {
    primary: '#FFA726',
    secondary: '#29B6F6',
    anyColor: '#0000'
}})
```

And you'll be able to call it like this in any of your app's component :

```js
color="primary"
```

or

```js
color="anyColor"
```

[Source and more info about Vuetify theme](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/theme)

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the variables before importing Vuetify. Switching the order of imports should work, assuming that `main.styl` imports your modified `_color.styl`.

Quote from the [documentation](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/style/theme#stylus-guide):

> Now that stylus is configured, you can set default values for the stylus variables that you wish to change. These **must be declared before the import** and will automatically override the Vuetify defaults.

You can see all the variables you can change in [here](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/tree/dev/src/stylus/settings).