# Theme style seems to override everything else

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to give an element in my page a custom colour but all attempts are foiled by the Vuetify enforcing the `important!` on the component themes. I have followed the docs and tried:

```
v-list-item.selection(class="red--text")
```

and

```
v-list-item.selection(color="red")
```

then got desperate and tried

```
.selection {
  color: red
}
```

and

```
.theme--light.v-list-item {
  color: red
}
```

But the theme color just overrules everything by applying:

```
.theme--light.v-list-item:not(.v-list-item--active):not(.v-list-item--disabled) {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87) !important;
}
```

What do?

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite it by adding the same rule in your `App.vue`:

```
.theme--light.v-list-item:not(.v-list-item--active):not(.v-list-item--disabled) {
    color: red !important;
}
```

Or you can increase specificity by adding your own class to that element:

```
<div class="custom-list-item"></div>

...

.custom-list-item {
    color: red !important;
}
```

Or you can specifically change `color` of all elements inside it, if it works for you:

```
.theme--light.v-list-item * {
    color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: I am really trying to avoid this approach for two reasons. First of all - using !important does not feel right and prevents elegant composable code. And styling the .theme--light elements by referincing them binds me to the lib-generated classes and will likely make things go wrong in the future.  What I want is for the documented way (my examples 1 and 2) to work.

Comment: @Rince I have tried myself and the `.v-application .red--text` was overridden by `.theme--light.v-list-item:not(.v-list-item--active):not(.v-list-item--disabled)` too, it seems to be a bug of Vuetify because `v-list-item` got too much of specificity by the `:not`s. Tried Replacing `v-list-item` with `v-subheader`, `class="red--text"` had made the text red as expected. Seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

One might work (but not a good practice at all):

```
.theme--light.v-list-item:not(.v-list-item--active):not(.v-list-item--disabled).selection {
    color: red !important;
}
// it's more than Vuetify's style the `.selection` specificity
```

---

#### Edit:

- The answer I gave above will not work if you use `scoped style`

As working around myself, and have read [a comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50215610/9787887). I don't think **change Vuetify's style in a Vuetify component** is easy. Instead, by using a Vuetify's component, you should predefine the colors you'll ever use, and then you could use those colors in the components you want.

To workaround without configuring Vuetify, then you can:

- Combine inline style + `!important`

```
<v-list-item style="color: red !important">Content</v-list-item>
```

- Don't use Vuetify's component, use vanilla html (for this component) instead